# How can I forward mail in Domino 8.5.3 without keeping a copy in the original recipient's mailbox?

Tags: rules, ibm-domino

I'm new to Domino and need to forward email that a user receives to another user. However, I do not want to keep a local copy of the message in the inbox of the original recipient. Can anyone explain to me how to do that?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that I'm using Lotus domino 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of an admin question and here is the answer:

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_admin.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/5dc869eda42a372e85256c1d0039546f?OpenDocument

Since I haven't used this feature before, I am not sure whether it will keep a copy in the intended recipient's mail box or not, but this is a step in the right direction, hope this helps. Let me know if you require further information.

If you find this solution useful, please make sure to mark it as accepted answer - thank you.

Comment: Hi, this relate to domino server 6, I forgot to say that I use version 8.5.3, so thanks for the link but it's not reliable as things have changed alot since then and most information included there isn't right for new version.

Comment: The documentation linked to also works for 8.5.x. You can use this if you want to forward ALL mails (it will not keep a copy).

Comment: Thank you for confirming that it will not keep a copy Per Henrik Lausten. Cividan unlike other technologies Notes does not need to and has not modified the base functionality for a while (they don't do a rip and replace for each version). So most of the documentation for v6 will be valid for the latest version, this makes it forward and backwards compatible - one of the beauty of using Notes. You can open a Notes 6 or even a Notes 5 db and it will work more or less without further modification in 8.5.3. Here is a link to 8.5.3 documentation: http://tinyurl.com/7a7szry.

Comment: Note, if you set up forwarding for a user as in the linked document, it will probably break the calendar functionality for that user, if they need it.